# Unable to read Temperature on my Ryzen 5 1600X

Tags: cpu, temperature, amd-processor, lm-sensors

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to get the Temperature of my Processor, a Ryzen 5 1600X. 
Sadly, everything I tried didn't work: Psensor, lm-sensor, xsensor - nothing. 
Can anyone recommend me a programm/tool or a fix for this?

Comment: Disclaimer: I was involved in creating s-tui.   s-tui is a tool to measure CPU temperature/Utilization/Frequency.
Try it: https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui

Comment: @amanusk your tool doesnt work for me either.

Comment: @Nimitz14 you are welcome to open an issue on github and I'll try to look into it. Ryzen 5 systems should be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo modprobe it87 force_id=0x8628
```

The above worked for me.